# How do I write a prepared statement with an update?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using mysqli prepared statments and I am trying to write a prepared statement with an UPDATE, but I think I am off somewhere.

Here's my code:

```
$upload_folder = 'Some String';
$sql = 'UPDATE orders (upload_location)
        SET (?)
        WHERE order_id = 160';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($sql)){
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $upload_folder);
  $location_inserted = $stmt->execute();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct sql-syntax for update is:

```
UPDATE table SET column = ?
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SET foo = ?
```

You haven't specified which column to update.

Answer (score 0):

you are using SET keqword instead of VALUES as it's supposed by query format.